# Get pid of the process which created the socket

Tags: ios, c, linux, linux-kernel, fcntl

How can i get pid of process which established a socket. I went through this [PDF link](http://www.haifux.org/lectures/217/netLec5.pdf), where he has mentioned **Calling fcntl() with F_SETOWN and the pid of our 
process to tell the process that it is the owner of the socket**.How can i get socket owner using fcntl()?

Comment: `The owner of a socket is unset when a socket is created. The owner may be set to a process ID or process group ID using the F_SETOWN command of the fcntl() function.` as mentioned in [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_10.html). To get the pid of your own process you can use `getpid()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the man pagr of fcntl()

*F_SETOWN (int)
Set the process ID or process group ID that will receive SIGIO and SIGURG signals for events on file descriptor fd to the ID given in arg. A process ID is specified as a positive value; a process group ID is specified as a negative value. Most commonly, the calling process specifies itself as the owner (that is, arg is specified as getpid(2)).*

You can use the getpid() to get the process ID. And on passing that to F_SETOWN, you are requesting that the the process be notified if the SD is readable or writable.

Specifically the answer to your titled question is getpid().

Comment: how to get pid of a process which established a socket using getpid()?

Comment: Not sure, I get your question. A process calls getpid() to determine its own ID.